# Dependency array in useEffect - should I pass all arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider situation:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
const ref = useRef(null);

const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
   if (value) {
      ref.current = 'something';
   }
}, [ref, value]);

useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
}, [handleClick]);
```

So you can see that `handleClick` uses `ref` and `value`, so it needs to be passed in the dep array of `useCallback`. But what about `useEffect`?

**Question**: Even if I passed `ref, value` in the dependency array in `useCallback`, should I also put it in the dependency array within `useEffect`?

So instead of

```
}, [handleClick]);
```

I would have

```
}, [handleClick, ref, value]);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You'll need `value` in the `useCallback` because the value is in the scope of the memoized function and you'll need `handleClick` on the `useEffect` because you want to use the updated function for the same reason. You should also add a return value to your `useEffect` to remove the listener

Here's a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-yonath-5pdcd?file=/src/App.js) have a play with the dependencies and check the console.log when you click it

Answer (score 1):

No.

The useCallback returns a memoised value - that will not change, so you don't need to worry about anything inside it.

Secondary to that you don't need to pass `ref` anywhere, as that is already memoised and not going to change.

It's worth using eslint and letting it look at what refs are being used, as it will report on the correct ones to pass in :-)

(For eslint it's `"react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"` in the `"eslint-plugin-react-hooks"` plugin)

Comment: I dont need to pass `ref` in useCallback?

Comment: Nope - it's not mentioned inside any code inside it, so it's not a dependency - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies - it can be a little confusing cross-referencing this, but `useCallback` makes the fn safe to pass on its own! :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, It's not necessary, since the function you provided into the `useEffect` is dependant on the `handleClick` which is dependant on `ref, value`, and as soon as one of those variables change, `React` will redeclare the `handleClick` function first which will trigger the function within the `useEffect` accordingly.

Comment: Technically this is actually wrong in the flow - `handleClick` is from `useCallback`, so it won't actually change the callback fn itself, so the useEffect won't be updated - think of `useCallback` as a small wrapper that lets you update the function without potentially doing something more expensive with it

Comment: I'm not here to argue, but I didn't say that the function will change, it "will be re-declared if value or ref changes" thus trigger the effect

Comment: It's a memoised callback - `This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders` - the reference itself will never change, so strict equality checks such as `useEffect` dependencies will say they are the same, and never re-render - hence anything that is known memoised (the `setValue` callback from `useState`, anything from `useRef`, and `useCallback` etc) is not needed as a dependency